# Selenium "Element not interactable"

Tags: java, python, selenium, web, element

I used python selenium for a web project, it worked perfectly with other web elements so far, but for this one element it always returns
"element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
(Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)"

The coding of the element I want to interact is

```
<select id="collection-arrangement" name="collectionArrangement" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="" ng-model="Bin.CollectionArrangement" ng-change="onCollectionArrangementChange(Bin.CollectionArrangement.id)" ng-options="type as type.value for type in CollectionArrangements track by type.value" aria-invalid="true" style=""><option value="" class="" selected="selected">-- select an option --</option><option label="Site pays for collection " value="Site pays for collection " selected="selected">Site pays for collection </option><option label="Waste Service Provider purchases materials" value="Waste Service Provider purchases materials">Waste Service Provider purchases materials</option><option label="Internal bin not collected by Waste Service Provider" value="Internal bin not collected by Waste Service Provider" selected="selected">Internal bin not collected by Waste Service Provider</option></select>
```

My codes are

```
collection_arrangement = '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/section/div/div[1]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/section/form/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/div/div/div/select'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,collection_arrangement)))
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(collection_arrangement))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(collection_arrangement).click()
select.select_by_value('Internal bin not collected by Waste Service Provider')
```

I want to select the option "internal bin not collected by waste service provider", but every time I ran this script, the curser till hovers on the last element, which means that this element cannot be found or manipulated?

Any ideas are really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're setting `collection_arrangement` to the XPATH of the `select` element, and then trying to use this for the `find_element_by_id` method rather than the actual `id`.

You also shouldn't need to manually click the element, so maybe try something like this:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('collection-arrangement'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Internal bin not collected by Waste Service Provider')
```

Feel free to keep your wait in there if necessary. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Hi Matt,

Thank you for your suggestion, however it still occurs that the element cannot be manipulated. The error code is "element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated". And I can see that the script curser still shows up at the element before, so is is possible that this is not the actual element I'm looking for? It did look like this is the one from the html code...

Comment: Hey Simon, so if you try to find the element normally then are you able to do so?

For example:
    `collection_arrangement = '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/section/div/div[1]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/section/form/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/div/div/div/select'`
    `driver.find_element_by_xpath(collection_arrangement)`

Comment: Hi Matt, unfortunately that does not work. The curser still doesn't move to the input box. Is is possible that this is not the actual element?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for the presence of the element, I would try waiting for it to be visible -- it is not when the click is executed, which causes that error. The code for the wait would be like this

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,collection_arrangement)))
```

Comment: Hi Peck, thank you for your suggestion, I changed the wait condition, but this time I received a time out and same error code as above, is there any other approach I can try? Thanks!

Comment: I think I would need some more information about/a link to the page you are testing to figure out what's really going on.  Not sure if you can provide that or if it's private.

Comment: Thanks Peck, I've posed an answer with a bit more information. Hopefully this can be helpful, thanks!

Comment: First of all, you should post additional info in your question, not create another answer. Second -- no, unfortunately that is not enough HTML to see what's going on, the full HTML will be needed, or a link.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply, unfortunately I cannot provide the link. Below are some screenshots of the page, is this going to be helpful?
[Html code for this section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSlof.png)

[Selections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXl8p.png)

[Input Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb2Ec.png)